# Adding Runnable Thread class to JAR file using Terminal

Tags: java, multithreading, jar

When I try to run the command

```
jar uvf Century.jar Century$1.class
```

from the command line, I get the following response:

```
adding: Century.class(in = 6441) (out= 3544)(deflated 44%)
```

Notice that instead of adding Century$1.class, is adds Century.class. The issue here is that Century$1.class is the class file for a new runnable thread that gets created in Century.class, which is the main class. Is there some way I can add the Century$1.class file to the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try any of

```
jar uvf Century.jar Century\$1.class

jar uvf Century.jar 'Century$1.class'
```

A unix shell will interpret $1 as the value of the first command line parameter which is not what you want, you want the $ verbatim.

And please remember to comment or accept an answer given to your last question [Datepicker Multiple Dates not working in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904225/datepicker-multiple-dates-not-working-in-google-apps-script)